# Using varchar column as partition in Teradata to speedup truncate

Tags: teradata

I have a Teradata table and two columns `company_name varchar(500)` and `case_name varchar(500)`.

The value of the two partitions are limited in hundreds level. But it is not controlled by me. And I can't predefine a set of their value.

It is a daily operation to truncate all data of specified `company_name` and `case_name`. So I want to use these two columns as partitions.

Is it supported to do so? And will it helps if truncate data by partition in TD? If this is not supported. Is there a best practice to truncate data by two varchar columns?

Comment: Do you access the table using equality only on those columns?

Comment: @dnoeth it is a factor table and there are around 100 other columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the access to those columns is (mainly) based on `where company_name = 'foo' and case_name = 'bar'` you can apply a calculation like this

```
PRIMARY INDEX ( PIcol)
PARTITION BY
   Range_N(HashBucket(HashRow(company_name,case_name)) MOD 65533 BETWEEN 0 AND 65532 EACH 1)
```

A `delete from where company_name = 'foo' and case_name = 'bar'` will access a single partition, but it's not a FastPath delete, it will be transient journaled.